# Amazon Product Advertising API changes: replacement for ListLookup & ListSearch?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

Amazon has announced to drop ListLookup & ListSearch operations support from the API completely from Oct 15.

Does anybody know whether there is a replacement operation to be used? Or some other way to retrieve a list I could not find anything like it in the documentation.

I need to import a user's wishlist through the API.

Thanks a lot for any hints & best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. This functionality is no longer available from Amazon, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It stopped working on my site. I assumed deprecated meant it won't work in the future, so don't build around it. I didn't think they'd remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Blatant **disclaimer** that I'm the CTO at [Wishpot.com](http://www.wishpot.com), but we have an OAuth-based [RESTful API for managing wishlists](http://www.wishpot.com/help/api.aspx), including the ability to add item to a Wishlist by Amazon ASIN, create users, manage lists, etc.  There has been a big jump in inbound contacts about our API since Amazon's announcement that they've ceased theirs.

We'd love to work with anyone on improving/expanding our API.  Items from any store can be added to our wishlists, and we support a number of features that Amazon never offered, like sending price alerts to users when things go on sale.

We're looking at a bunch of new API features, including a JSON option to make JavaScript integrations easier, but would love to hear from developers on things they'd like to see added/changed/etc.